Best way to deal with a large dataset?
I am working on a project with a team of 4 people, on a relatively large dataset (around 500Gb). I cleaned the data and did some feature engineering, and now I want everyone to have simple access to the dataset. I have been looking at some cloud solutions, but I wonder if it might be overkill for our needs. We started by sharing some huge .csv files but in the end it is not viable, some of us don't even have enough local storage to deal with the whole dataset.
The dataset is divided in two parts : one consisting in 2D time-series, and one consisting of tabular data.
I understand this is a very common issue, but I have not been able to find relevant answers online. Disclaimer: I'm a very beginner on everything related to "at-scale" data-engineering.

It's hard to give an answer because a lot of it depends on the details of what you are trying to do and what budget you're operating on. Do you expect the dataset to grow, and if so by how much? Do you want to do database stuff/SQL-type queries? Do you want to do ETL pipelines? Do you want to extract features and save blobs? Are you at a company or paying out of pocket? What level of spend would be considered significant? $(1, 10, 100, 1000)/month?

Thanks for your answer.
It's an academic project, so the budget is tight (around 30$/month).
The dataset will not grow.
For now the main goal is to to clustering analysis (K-means etc) on our data, but given the size of the dataset we can not do anything locally because our memory is too small.
From what I understand, we could use something like Apache Spark and MLlib directly in the Google Cloud Console.
But is it really how it should be done?

The first step might be to convert the dataset into something that compresses the data and that allows access to individual data records without having to read the whole dataset into memory. HDF5 might be one of such solutions. There even might be hope that the size of the dataset is then significantly smaller, making it much easier to handle.

If you're being super lean, you can try doing everything on S3. You can save the dataset to S3, do ETL/data processing with the datasets library connected to S3 link, and save computed feature blobs to S3

As a general advice, I recommend to sub-sample the dataset to a more manageable size and test your ideas on it first, until you are solid on what the exact work/technique would be. Always best to start simple.
